# Test volatile variable in java

Tags: java, data-structures

I wrote a simple program to test volatile variables. As for the program I have written when t2 runs, it should pick value of i as 3 and should never go inside the while loop

but it outputs
0
1
2
0
1
2
since it is volatile shouldnt it print just 0,1,2 ??

```
public class Test{
     public static void main(String []args) throws InterruptedException{      
          TestVolatile t1 = new TestVolatile();
          t1.start();
          t1.join();
          TestVolatile t2 = new TestVolatile();
          t2.start();  
     }
}

class TestVolatile extends Thread{
    volatile int i = 0;  
    public void run(){
        while(i < 3){
            System.out.println(i);
            i++;
        }
    }   
}
```

Comment: Seriously: if you don't understand that you need *static* here, then you trying to learn about volatile, and threads and what not ... is like very inefficient. Learn the basics, first. Then the advanced stuff.

Answer (score 0):

You are creating 2 different `TestVolatile` objects and each of them has its own variable `i` and works only with it. So first object increments and outputs 0, 1, 2 and so does the second.

You need tomake `i` static like this

```
static volatile int i = 0;
```

Comment: And even then, note that `i++` is not thread safe, even if `i` is volatile. I'm on a phone now so I can't easily check, but searching for "Java volatile increment" or similar will probably give you the reason why.

Comment: @yshavit, there will be happens-before relation because of starting second thread after `join()`. So `volatile` could be omitted in this case at all.

Answer (score 0):

Since 2 threads are accessing 2 copies of the i variable you got the output.

Make the i variable static -

`static volatile int i = 0;`

For more info - https://www.javacodegeeks.com/2018/03/volatile-java-works-example-volatile-keyword-java.html